# Executing Mojo failed with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.setFilenameComparator

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, mojo

I have created 2 `Mojo`s and recently decided to upgrade all my versions usign the maven version plugin.

Now, an executing one of my `Mojo`s, I get this exception:

```
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.mycompany:spi2jars-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:spi2jars:

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.setFilenameComparator(java.util.Comparator)
```

I know what this errors means, and I retrieve the full stacktrace by running with `-X`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.setFilenameComparator(java.util.Comparator)'
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.getResources (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext (AbstractArchiver.java:560)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain (AbstractZipArchiver.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute (AbstractZipArchiver.java:199)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:1042)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive (MavenArchiver.java:676)
    at com.mycompany.Spi2Jars.createJarForLine (Spi2Jars.java:81)
    at com.mycompany.Spi2Jars.execute (Spi2Jars.java:47)
```

So it seems the MavenArchiver is at fault, or maybe a missing jar or incompatible versions.. But how do I check this?

[Update]

I found different versions of the underlying jars using

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

For example:

```
\- org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- (org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.6.0)
[INFO]    +- (org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.6.3)
[INFO]    +- (org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.6.3)
[INFO]    +- (org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.8:runtime
[INFO]    +- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO]    \- (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.25:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.11)
```

It would be so awesome if the most recent maven plugins played nice together... It seems they don't. How do I resolve this nicely?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue (same error message).

I could solve this isse by declaring the following direct dependency in our custom plugin:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```